# CodeIgniter Active Record Like 3rd Parameter

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, sql-like

According to the documentation, passing a third parameter of 'none' to the like method should eliminate the use of wildcard characters in a like search query.

Im doing this, where $search == 'test_username':

```
$this->db->like('username', $search, 'none');
$this->db->limit(1);
$q = $this->db->get('customers')->row();
var_dump($this->db->last_query());exit;
```

I expect to see this echoed to the screen:

```
SELECT * FROM (`ci_customers`) WHERE `username` LIKE 'test_username' LIMIT 1
```

But I'm getting this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM (`ci_customers`) WHERE `username` LIKE '%test_username%' LIMIT 1
```

It seems like the method is ignoring the 3rd parameter or I'm doing something wrong.  Any Ideas?  I can just write out my query and use the `query()` method but I'm curious.

Comment: Yeah, that's the way it is supposed to work ( http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html ). What version of CI are you running?

Comment: Im running Version 2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though the code for the "none" is not included in the 2.1.0 version. Have a look at lines 649-692 on https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/v2.1.0/system/database/DB_active_rec.php#L639.

and then look at line 664 of the 2.1.3 version: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1.3/system/database/DB_active_rec.php#L639

You either need to upgrade, or add this to your `DB_active_rec.php` file:

```
...
if ($side == 'none')
{
  $like_statement = $prefix." $k $not LIKE '{$v}'";
}
...
```

Comment: ahhhh.  Nice catch.  I was trying to check the core files but I couldn't locate the right file.  Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: No problem, it's in the 2.1.0 docs but apparently was omitted from the code.